# R - forcing a set of indexed rows to always be a matrix (or array)

Tags: r, array-indexing

I have a matrix that I need to filter by a condition.

```
yj = y[which(g[,j] == 1),]
```

A problem arises when "which(g[,j] == 1)" is a 1 (or none) component vector.  The output, the aforementioned "yj", is then suddenly a vector.  I need to be able to reference it by column.  Even if it's a single row, it still needs to be reference-able by column.

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop = FALSE` while subsetting.

```
yj = y[which(g[,j] == 1),, drop = FALSE]
```

If `which(g[,j] == 1)` can be of length 0 better to check for it using `if` condition.

```
inds <- which(g[,j] == 1)
if(inds) yj = y[inds, ,drop = FALSE]
```